# how to convert a string IP into IP address in Jinja2?

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2

I have jinja2 yaml file with content:

```
{% set mal_ip = '2.2.0.1' %}
```

I am using the above mal_ip in yaml file as:

```
ipv4: {{ config.malicious_ip }}
```

but the ipv4 only takes IP address, not in string format
how can I convert the String IP to IP address here?

I looked at jinja2 filters but could not find anything unless i install some custom filters?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ipv4` filter available from jinja2 1.9

```
ipv4: {{ config.malicious_ip | ipv4  }}
```

or [ipaddr](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/Ansible.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters_ipaddr.html)

You may have to install netaddr

```
pip install netaddr
```